# wayland login loop after moving $HOME to new SSD

Tags: xorg, gdm, wayland

TR;DR
I moved my home dir to a new SSD and manually changed owner to my user. Now I cannot log into wayland unless I log in to Xorg session first.

I moved my home directory to a new SSD using `rsync -avz`.
Some apps were having issues accessing the configs, so I ran `sudo chown USERNAME *` on my home dir. This seemed to work but now I have a login loop on wayland.

On a fresh startup GDM3 does not give options for session. It will automatically start an Xorg session. I can then log out and log back in to get the usual options : sway, ubuntu and ubuntu on Xorg.
Sway starts up. Ubuntu (on wayland) has a boot loop, ubuntu on Xorg starts up.

Any suggestions on what could be causing this?

*EDIT*

Looks like this issue: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=884189

Comment: Did you update fstab with new UUID for /home partition. Or add entry if it was not a separate partition before? To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: The fstab is updated and the home directory is in place (I can access file without issues). It is too late for me to use the ```-aSX``` options on rsync.

Comment: I did a comparison of the permissions for the content of the original files and the new dir, there doesn't seem to be much difference.

Comment: Your /home or data only partitions or folders can easily be reset to defaults. You cannot reset / or most root folders so have to be careful on any commands. Ubuntu Home directories were created with 755 permissions but will be dropped to 750 with 21.04,  now to prevent new home directories from being readable by other users on the system. I sometimes use sudo when I should not and root owns a file or two. So I concessional run these: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER`  /home/$USER` & 
`sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /home/$USER` Note /R is recursion, so all lower level folders also changed.

Comment: I ran both those commands and it hasn't changed the gdm3 issue. Another issue that has came up at the same time is my wifi does not connect automatically. I need to manually select to connect to the wifi.

Comment: Do not know wayland or gdm, but wifi issue should be a separate question. Do you have any related errors in log files. I get a bunch of warnings that do not really matter. `sudo egrep -i 'warn|error' /var/log/*log |less` With less  spacebar for next screen & q to quit.

Comment: I have now unmounted the new home dir, remounted the old home (using fstab and a reboot) but this did not resolve the issue. My guess now is that the problem doesn't have anything to do with my home directory moving.... perhaps an update broke something...